# Script getting executed correctly once page is refreshed - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, window-load

In my webpage I have script like this :

```
<head>
<script src="scripts/effect.js"></script>
<script>
if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
  doOnLoad();
}
$(window).bind("load", doOnLoad);
function doOnLoad() {
    console.log("here..");
}
</script>
</head>
```

**effect.js** file contains script as shown below:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    console.log("yes");
   // here I've script for reading a text file using ajax and manipulating the result from text file
    $.ajax({
      // code goes here
      console.log("ajax");
    });
});
```

The problem is that when I run the page initially, I'm not getting the result. At that time I get console output as

```
yes
here..
ajax
```

But when I refresh the page again I am getting the result and console prints like :

```
yes
ajax
here..
```

How can I run `window.load` after the `document.ready` is completed.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works fine for me, I am getting `yes here..` on initial load also

Comment: It sounds like a simple race condition. Out of interest, on the reload is `effect.js` being retrieved from the cache?

Comment: @jakob..I have some scripts inside the `document.ready`..That is executing after the `window.load`..I want to run those before `window.load`.

Comment: Use callback functions instead of `window.load`?

Comment: If you have a function that depends on a ajax call, you should be able to run that function on the return of the ajax call, or have a way to notify the function that the ajax call is finished. You don't need to bind the function on *window.onload*. Instead, you should define a custom event and bind your function to this, then fire the custom event when you're back from your ajax call. This keep separation of concern.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about the timing of script execution.  It sounds like the behaviour is changing once certain resources have been loaded and cached.

The first piece of code you have is a bit confusing:

```
if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    doOnLoad();
}
```

I'm not sure why you need this as well as the on load handler?  It looks like that condition is never going to equal true anyway, as that code will run immediately before the document has finished loading.  At the very least, I would put a console.log in this block, so I could determine what's triggering doOnLoad.

Try replacing the script on your page for just the following:

```
$(window).on("load", doOnLoad);
function doOnLoad() {
    console.log("here..");
}
```